# Finding Duplications with Pandas Pivot Table Works The First Time, Fails Second Time Forward

Tags: python, django, pandas, pivot-table, xlsx

We use Django framework and have created an api that takes
an xlsx file that is then processed into a dataframe to gather
duplication values and count of duplications

```
def duplicationCount(table_file_path, targetColumns):
    dfTable = pd.read_excel(io=table_file_path, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=0)
    dfTable.columns = dfTable.columns.str.strip("'")
    res = dfTable.pivot_table(index=targetColumns, aggfunc='size')
    res.reset_index()
    res.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'no of dups'}, inplace=True)
    res.index.name = 'index'
    res = res[res['no of dups'] >= 2]
    targetColumns.extend(['no of dups'])
    res = res.filter(targetColumns).values.tolist()
    return res
```

This works well the first time with output containing for example:

| account | year | no of dups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10301 | 2022 | 2 |
| 42334 | 2022 | 2 |

but calling this api the second time from the frontend using the same code and the same file, we get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programs\XX\backend\app\views.py", line 265, in app_process_text_file
    results['DuplicationReportResults'] = duplicationCount(tables_file_paths[0], dupsFindingTargets)
  File "E:\Programs\XX\backend\app\functions.py", line 92, in duplicationCount
    res = dfTable.pivot_table(index=targetColumns, aggfunc='size')
  File "E:\Programs\XX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8044, in pivot_table
    return pivot_table(
  File "E:\Programs\XX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 95, in pivot_table
    table = __internal_pivot_table(
  File "E:\Programs\XX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 164, in __internal_pivot_table
    grouped = data.groupby(keys, observed=observed, sort=sort)
  File "E:\Programs\XX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7718, in groupby
    return DataFrameGroupBy(
  File "E:\Programs\XX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 882, in __init__
    grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
  File "E:\Programs\XX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 882, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'no of dups'
```

Answer (score 0):

dupsFindingTargets seems to be a mutable object. You modify this within the function by doing targetColumns.extend(['no of dups']). This change will now also be in the dupsFindingTargets outside of the function. So when you call it again dupsFindingTargets will already containt "no of dups" which raises the error as you not have added the column to the table yet. So make sure you reset the dupsFindingTargets variable before calling the function.
Or you can just copy the object within you function putting as first line :

```
targetColumns=targetColumns[:]
```